# rails global variable inaccessible in thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, redis, faye

I'm using Faye websockets and Redis to attempt a master/client websocket setup for a slideshow presentation.
The clients' should all follow along with the master (i.e. the master moves forward a slide, a message is sent out to all of the clients, and they all move forward a slide).

The issue I'm having is that my list of client websockets is empty when I access inside the thread created in the initialize function. The separate thread is necessary as Redis' 'subscribe' is a blocking function.
This file is a middleware and runs on app boot up.

I know that the *point* of global variables in rails is that they're shared across threads, but in my case something seems to be preventing it.

Is there a way to store a list of websockets in a globally accessible place? Globally, as in, for all running instances of the app on the same server. 
(can't use Redis for that cause it can't store objects).

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'redis'

class WsCommunication
  KEEPALIVE_TIME = 15 #seconds
  CHANNEL = 'vip'

def initialize(app)
@app = app
$clients = []

uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'])
Thread.new do
  redis_sub = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
  redis_sub.subscribe(CHANNEL) do |on|
    on.message do |channel, msg|
      puts 'client list on thread'
      puts $clients
      #### prints nothing
      $clients.each { |ws| ws.send(msg) }
    end
  end
end
end

def call(env)
if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
  ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: KEEPALIVE_TIME})
  ws.on :open do |event|
    $clients << ws
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    puts 'client list'
    puts $clients
    ### prints the full list of clients
    $redis.publish(CHANNEL, event.data)
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    $clients.delete(ws)
    ws = nil
  end

  # Return async Rack response
  ws.rack_response
else
  @app.call(env)
end
end

end
```